# How to use repalce function to change string from query in oracle

Tags: oracle

```
select replace (SELECT TO_CHAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) FROM DUAL,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'2015-03-10 11:45:15') As result from dual;
```

I want to change CURRENT_TIMESTAMP with '2015-03-10 11:45:15' but oracle gives
error.However if you remove select statement then it works fine I mean

```
select replace (TO_CHAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'2015-03-10 11:45:15') As result from dual;
```

this works fine but I have so long query and CURRENT_TIMESTAMP coming several times and I want to replace it with given string

It is working fine in mysql I want it in oracle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the brackets around the subquery:

```
select replace ((SELECT TO_CHAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) FROM DUAL),CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'2015-03-10 11:45:15') As result
from dual;
```

However, this is badly written. Your `TO_CHAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)` has no format mask, which means your conversion of the timestamp to the string is reliant on your nls settings. This is bad practice.

Also, the `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` in the second parameter of your replace statement is undergoing an implicit conversion into a string, again relying on your nls settings.

If I were you, I'd write it as:

```
select replace ((SELECT TO_CHAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') FROM DUAL),
                TO_CHAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'),
                '2015-03-10 11:45:15') As result
from dual;
```

Comment: In actual query I have given format mask but this is only for example.Thanks Boneist for solution

Comment: Hi Bon,

What if ,if there is multiple occurrence of string .because it gives to many value errors

Comment: You'd have to provide more information - eg. something that accurately reflects the situation you're in. Since you marked this question answered, probably best to start a new one.